# How do you extract the payload length from an ipv6 header in linux?

Tags: linux, ipv6

How do you extract the payload length from an ipv6 header in linux ?

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 <packet_file>"
    exit 1
fi


packet_file="$1"


header_hex=$(xxd -p -l 40 "$packet_file")


payload_length_hex=$(echo "$header_hex" | cut -c 10-17)
payload_length_decimal=$((0x$payload_length_hex))


source_address_hex=$(echo "$header_hex" | cut -c 18-49)


destination_address_hex=$(echo "$header_hex" | cut -c 50-81)

payload_hex=$(hexdump -s 40 -ve '/1 "%02x"' "$packet_file")
payload_length_from_hexdump=$((16#${payload_hex:0:8}))

if [ "$payload_length_decimal" -eq "$payload_length_from_hexdump" ]; then
    echo "Payload Length: $payload_length_decimal"
    echo "Source Address: $source_address_hex"
    echo "Destination Address: $destination_address_hex"
    echo "Payload length matches!"
else
    echo "Payload Length: $payload_length_decimal"
    echo "Source Address: $source_address_hex"
    echo "Destination Address: $destination_address_hex"
    echo "Payload length does not match!"
fi
```

This code isn't working correctly.

The payload length won't print.

Comment: Define "isn't working correctly" and "payload length won't print". What happens instead?

Comment: You need to convert from network byte order to host byte order.

Comment: how do you do that ?

Comment: script.sh: line 16: 0x1ff06402
00001f12: value too great for base (error token is "00001f12")
script.sh: line 27: [: : integer expression expected
Payload Length: 
Source Address: 407e400803cfe005c770972e68cba2e2
000
Destination Address: 604a8800004
Payload length does not match!    this is what it prints

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.